# Another poker combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I would like to know if I'm solving the following problem correctly.

Problem: 
Three people are playing poker, Jessica, Adam and Ida. There's a Ace of spades, Queen of diamonds and a 10 of clubs on the table. Ida have a Queen of spades and a 10 of spades in her hand.

How many different pair of cards could Jessica (or Adam) have that gives a better poker hand than Ida's?

So I calculated this one to that there were 33 different pair of cards that gives a better poker hand then Ida's.

But then there's this question:
How many different pair of cards could Adam **and** Jessica have so that **both** have a better poker hand than Ida's?

So for this one I went through all of the cases and got the answer 144 * 2, I'm not sure if this is the right answer though. From the question above this I got that there were 6 poker hands possible that was better than Ida's so what I did here was to check for example if Jessica had case 1 how it affected the other 5 cases for Adam and I did this for all 6 cases.

Comment: It would really help if you show your work that led you to those answers!

Answer (score 0):

Ummm,

You correctly calculated that 33 holdings could now be better than Ida's, these are combinations of the following hands:
**AT -> 6 possibilities**
**AQ -> 6 possibilities**
**AA -> 3 possibilities**
**QQ -> 1 possibility**
**TT -> 1 possibility**
**KJ -> 16 possibilities**

Now, if you remove 1 holding from each set (say you assign that holding to Adam), that would leave you with:
**AT -> 2 possibilities**
**AQ -> 2 possibilities**
**AA -> 0 possibilities**
**QQ -> 0 possibility**
**TT -> 0 possibility**
**KJ -> 9 possibilities**

Now you simply need to compute on set from the bottom group with the remaining sets form the top group:
2 + 6 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 16 = 29 
6 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 16 = 29 
6 + 6 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 16 = 30 
6 + 6 + 3 + 1 + 0 + 16 = 32 
6 + 6 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 9= 26

So the maximum number of holdings would be 33 (not forgetting about Adam's one)